# Compare values from two columns and return in 3rd column if there is mach

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I need to compare and mach a value from column B to a values from column A.
The criteria I need to fulfil are.

1. The comparison and mach should be performed for standard timestamps. (Starting point of column A values need to be timestamp of value from column B that need to be looked for. And stop time a month of registers of column A value after start point. Or 50 values of column A starting from same row as the comparison valu from column A)

Hope it makes sense. I did that on excel but I am trying to do it on Power Bi or excel query

Example:

look for value B1 in the rangeA1-A51 if found return "Yes" otherwise "no" in C1
( is it easier to check the range of A column values from the date Column ?)

Look for B2 in range B2-B52 if found return "Yes" otherwise "no" in C2

Look for B3 in range B3-B53 if found return "Yes" otherwise "no" in C3
.........

```
Date  column A  column B  Column C
1       124       136       Yes    
2       245       268        No
3       567       456        Yes
4       136       744        No
5       566       909        Yes
6       456       888        No
7       555       434        No
8       909       111        No
9       439       222        Yes
.       ...       ...        ...
.       ...       ...        ...
.       ...       ...        .. 
48      481       333        No
49      222       767        No
50      989       321        No
51      790       015        No
```

Comment: Can you explain the bigger picture of what you want to achieve? It also seems that the first lookup is in column A, but the next rows look in column B for the value of the same row in column B?? Are you sure? Also, which tool are you using? Excel or Power BI? Some things are easy in the data model using DAX, but hard to do in Power Query and vice versa. So, if you explain WHY you want to look up the number, the overall purpose of this exercise, it might help determine how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to be achieved through a DAX calculated column

```
Column C =
IF ( ( 'Table'[column B] ) IN VALUES ( 'Table'[column A] ), "Yes", "No" )
```

If you want this to be achieved through a DAX measure

```
Measure = 
VAR _lookUP = CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Table'[column A] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Table' ),
        ( 'Table'[column A] ) IN SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[column B] )
    )
)
RETURN IF(_lookUP=BLANK(),"No","Yes")
```

Comment: How would you wright the above in advanced editor? I am struggling to add a calculated colum  in power query.